# NullPointerException when generating signed APK with IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, apk, android-build

After upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2, I see the following exception when generating signed APK, the APK was generated though.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard$3.run(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:321)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.a(LaterInvocator.java:337)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:321)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This and other similiar ones are internal IDE errors and in my experience won't affect the final APK file. Although there may still be some hidden vulnerablilties, but I recommend to report the issue to the JetBrains team first and then try the same process after File --> Invalidate cache and Restart.

If the problem still persists, try the build process with a lower version.
After all, I recommend to migrate the project to Android Studio.